# как можно взять текст из динамически заполненного элемента listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Мне нужно поочередно зашифровать каждый элемент списка ListView. Для этого я с помощью цикла for хочу взять текст из элемента, зашифровать его и вернуть обратно в список, но не знаю как сделать так чтобы в стринговую переменную поочерёдно входили содержимые элементов списка

Answer (score 0):

Пишете в адаптере геттер, который будет выдавать текущий список. Потом получаете данные и делайте с ними что хотите. Когда все сделали, загружаете обратно.

```
List<someObject> myList = mAdapter.getMyList();
...
mAdapter.setList(list);
```

Comment: Если например полученный лист в цикле обработать, то изменения в силу не вступят, потому что итератор )

Comment: @Flippy, обработанные данные можно в другой лист сохранять, но вопрос ведь про их получение, а не обработку. Хотя ответ все же поправил ))